# NodeJS/JavaScript - Read File by passing command results from child_process as filepath for "fs.readFile"

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am currently having trouble with what is most likely a very simple function for most.

I have what I call a **Find & Read** function.

The "**find**" part of the function utilises a `child_process` with the `find -name` command in order to locate a given file by name and extension,

the "**Read**" part of the function is where the problem seems to be.

The **"Read"** part of the function is supposed to use the results from the command executed in the `child_process`, in a seperate variable, in order to start reading the file using `fs.readFile`, however everything I have tried presents me with the following error in the console...

```
Locating File...

File Found: this/way/to/the/File.txt

Reading File...

Reading File Failed!

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'this/way/to/the/File.txt'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at /home/user/test/index.js:23:8
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:390:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:451:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:710:12) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'this/way/to/the/File.txt'
}
```

However the isn't correct, the file actually does exist inside the directory found by the command executed in the `child_process` but it's still throwing me errors saying the file doesn't exist... if the file didn't exist, it wouldn't have located and printed its location in the console... so I'm not sure where the error is coming from here, hence why I've come StackOverflow for help.

I am using the JavaScript coding below to to try and achieve this...

### Find & Read function

```js
var exec = require("child_process").exec, child;
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');


// This seems to be working fine to locate the file
var folder = '/just/some/folder/location/';
var file = "File.txt";
console.log("Locating File...")
console.log();
exec('find -name ' + file, { cwd: folder }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    var filePath = stdout.substring(stdout.indexOf("./") + 2).split("\n")[0];
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log("Locating Failed Failed!");
      console.log(error);
      console.log(stderr);
      return;
    }
    
    // but it fails to read the file afterwards
    console.log("File Found: " + filePath); // print filepath in the log to confirm the file was found
    console.log();
    console.log("Reading File...");
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Reading File Failed');
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The problem was located within the `filePath` variable.

What was happening was, I didn't join both the `folder` variable & the `filePath` variable together with `path.join()` once the `file` was located!

For some reason as well, the instance of `.trim("\n")[0])` at the end of the `filePath` variable needed to be changed to an instance of `.trim("\n"))`... Because for some reason the former coding was causing problems with the function as well.

### Fix that was implemented

The below instance of the filePath variable...

```js
var filePath = stdout.substring(stdout.indexOf("./") + 2).split("\n")[0];
```

Was was changed to the following...

```js
var filePath = path.join(apkFolder, stdout.substring(stdout.indexOf("./") + 2).split("\n"));
```

Which now runs beautifully, the file gets located and it gets read beautifully!

Here's the Full fixed code below...

```js
var folder = '/just/some/folder/location/';
var file = "File.txt";
console.log("Locating File...")
console.log();
exec('find -name ' + file, { cwd: folder }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    var filePath = path.join(folder, stdout.substring(stdout.indexOf("./") + 2).split("\n")); // Fix contained here
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log("Locating File Failed!");
      console.log(error);
      console.log(stderr);
      return;
    }
    
    console.log("File Found: " + filePath);
    console.log();
    console.log("Reading File...");
    fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8', (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Reading File Failed');
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }

    });

});
```